# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context Swift map CBPeripheralDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, uiapplicationdelegate

I am getting a 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context ' on this part of code from a project.
I tried different things but can't get it to work.

The problem is on the syntax of this line:

```
.map { args -> (CBCharacteristic, Error?) in
                let characteristic = args[1] as! CBCharacteristic
                let error = args[2] as? Error
                return (characteristic, error)
        }
```

Full code:

```
var didUpdateValue: ControlEvent<(CBCharacteristic, Error?)> {
        let events = delegate
            .methodInvoked(#selector(CBPeripheralDelegate.peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:) as ((CBPeripheralDelegate) -> (CBPeripheral, CBCharacteristic, Error?) -> Void)?))
            .map { args -> (CBCharacteristic, Error?) in
                let characteristic = args[1] as! CBCharacteristic
                let error = args[2] as? Error
                return (characteristic, error)
        }
    
        
        return ControlEvent(events: events)
    }
```

I tried different aproximations but no combination of parameters works for me.
My project wont compile without it.